# What is the "interfaceId" referring to in chrome.usb.findDevices() and chrome.usb.requestAccess()?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to get a USB device to work on ChromeOS, and I'm running into an issue.  From what I understand, I need to do this for the device I'm trying to utilize:

```
chrome.usb.requestAccess(Device device, integer interfaceId, function callback)
```

or, I can use:

```
chrome.usb.findDevices(Device device, function callback)
```

Whichever one I choose, I need to provide the interfaceId (as part of the device tuple in findDevices, or as the second parameter in requestAccess)

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb#method-findDevices

```
vendorId    
productId   
interfaceId  (The interface id to request access against. Only available on ChromeOS. It has no effect on other platforms.)
```

I cannot find any documentation regarding this anywhere -- and nothing I try seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused too and then I found the answer in the specifications of the function:

integer (optional) interfaceId 
Since Chrome 29. The interface ID to request access to. Only available on Chrome OS. It has no effect on other platforms.

Referred to: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb#method-findDevices

Comment: Sorry, but how is this helpful? Considering the question is explicitly about ChromeOS and cites the same paragraph from the docs.